# Angular 12 'ng serve' builds apps slowly, almost like production builds

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12

I've just migrated an app from Angular 11.2.7 to Angular 12. Everything runs fine, except that when I am developing and using 'ng serve', rebuild times are much, much slower now, to the point where it's frustrating.

I'm on an M1 iMac, using node 16.1.0, for what it's worth.

The machine was lightning fast at dev rebuilds (sub-second) before I moved to Angular 12. Now if I change just one line of code, even if I just change one letter in a console log, build times are 23 seconds, roughly 22 seconds of which are taken up with "phase: sealing".

I've also noticed that everything now runs from a minified 'main.js" even when ng serving. I seem to recall version 11 didn't do that, but ran individual un-minified components during dev. Which is to say, ng serve now seems to be doing something like full a production build *every time* I change anything. I think that's the root cause of the slowness, but I'm not sure.

So . . .

Should I still be using 'ng serve' for development in Angular 12?

Is there an option that needs to be set when you migrate, perhaps to turn off full minified rebuilds, to maintain the old build speed?

What is this 'sealing phase', anyway? It sounds like a production build term to me!

thanks

John

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to Angular 12, but I'm using TailwindCSS and I though that is somehow related to it (postcss, purge, etc).

Comment: I wonder if something changed to @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server ...

Comment: There's an **[open issue already](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20713)**

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The angular cli got updated with v12 to have the development environment be more like production.

Or as they like to call it:

> The aim of these changes is to reduce the configuration complexity and support the new "production builds by default" initiative.

Judging by what they've changed, you should update your `angular.json` and update the `projects.{PROJECT_NAME}.architect.build.defaultConfiguration` path:

```
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/656f8d75a3368a5affd1c55145841123dafdb007)

If you did not use the `ng update` command, but manually updated using `npm`, you need to run migrations. Specifically the material styling had some changes which can cause long build times if not migrated. To trigger these migrations run:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 11 --to 12
```

Comment: I took your answer as the starting point and did this: created a brand new Angular 12 app, diffed angular.json in the migrated app against angular.json in the new app (there are a lot of differences, too many to mention here!) and brought the migrated app into line with the new app. It is now super fast again. Thanks!

Comment: The "compare selected files" function in Visual Studio Code is *brilliant* for live, editable diffing of two files to bring them into line, just by the way.

Comment: @John did you try the migrate command i gave? It should have done the trick as well :D

Comment: I tried it, but it gave me an error and changed no config files. I'm mildly concerned that there may be other files that, like angular.json, need to be migrated. The Angular Material update changed some CSS, but nothing else got changed in the upgrade.

Comment: @PoulKruijt thanks, it worked for me! Please note I also needed to set: `(...).build.defaultConfiguration` to `"development"`. Otherwise it was implicitly production. Angular automated migration didn't do it for me, because I used a custom builder `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server`. See the srouce code of the migration: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/migrations/update-12/production-default-config.ts#L21-L41

Comment: Thanks! This was finally what solved all my Angular12 issues!  Thanks @PoulKruijt This information should be plastered all over the Angular.io and NX docs.  Would have made my life much easier! Been struggling with slow serves for a whole week now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran the migration command and now everything is fine :) - Compilation went from 30 to 3 seconds

Answer (score 42):

I had to add the following to my config. My new app didnt seem to have any "development" configuration.

In `angular.json`

```json
"configurations": {
  "development": {
    "optimization": false,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "budgets": []
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "ui:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "ui:build:development"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, upgraded my project to Angular 13 and was having the exact issues of OP. This sped up compilation about 20x.

Comment: Same here. Upgraded from 11 to 13 and didn't get why my errors became unreadable. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 32):

If you're manually copying over bits and pieces from a clean angular.json (and you absolutely should do this), make sure you don't miss `"defaultConfiguration": "development"` under `serve`.

My previous angular.json didn't have this, which frankly could have been my mistake - or it might be a feature that came along after the fact. I was *still* getting a production build, which is super frustrating because it takes 3 minutes and nothing tells you which build it's doing.

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "angular12:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "angular12:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

You'll know you have a dev build when:

1. Viewing source in browser devtools shows your code and comments not all in one line.
2. Lazy Chunk Files have long filenames like `default-src_app_common-crm_common-crm_module_ts.js` and not `34.js`

Also, personally I choose to turn off `sourceMap`. It makes my compilation a lot faster and I can always enable if it I really need it.

---

### Very important:

It looks like there's a 'bug-like behavior' with the migrations if you run them more than once. If the `aot` setting is currently true then the migration will remove it (because the default is true, so it's redundant). However if you run it again (with the aot setting missing) then it will get written as `false` and effectively disabled (because it thinks you're migrating from 11 where its absense meant false and it thinks you want it to remain false).

```
 ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 11 --to 12
```

So running migrations can actually give the illusion of speeding up the build, but in reality it is actually only disabling aot.

In other words don't run this if you've already run `ng update` and look at your `angular.json` file carefully.

Comment: With that said I'm still seeing builds taking almost 3 times as long as before. It might just be webpack 5 but if that's the case they urgently need to find a workaround because this just isn't going to work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20979

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a solution from the other answers in this post. I did manage to eventually eliminate this issue by running `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only update-angular-config-v12`. Note: the migrations mentioned in the accepted answer did not work for me either, I kept getting an error stating "Package was not installed".